# Missing return statement error even though return statement in used

Tags: java, exception, stack

I've started learning User defined exceptions in Java. And I've created a simple stack program  for implementing my own Stack overflow and Stack underflow exception. Everything is fine, but I get the "missing return statement error" in the pop block even though I've returned a value.

**Code:**

```
import java.io.*;
class StackFullException extends Exception
{
    private int a;
    StackFullException(int x)
    {
        a=x;
    }
    public String toString()
    {
        return "Stack Overflow";
    }
}

class StackEmptyException extends Exception
{
    private int a;
    StackEmptyException(int x)
    {
       a=x;
    }
    public String toString()
    {
       return "Stack underflow";
    }
}

class Stack
{
    int n=5;
    int top=-1;
    int st[]=new int[10];
    void push(int val)
    {
        try
        {
            if(top==n-1)
            {
                throw new StackFullException(top);
            }
            else
            {
                top++;
                st[top]=val;
            }
        }
       catch(StackFullException e)
       {
           System.out.print("\n"+e);
       }
}

int pop()
{
    try
    {
        if(top==-1)
            throw new StackEmptyException(top);
        else
        {
            int tmp;
            tmp=st[top];
            top--;
            return tmp;
        }
    }
    catch(StackEmptyException e)
    {
        System.out.print("\n"+e);
    }
}
}

class StackDemo
{
public static void main(String args[])throws IOException
{
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
int item;
Stack s=new Stack();
System.out.print("\nEnter the elements :");
for(int i=0;i<7;i++)
{
item=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
s.push(item);
}
}
}
```

Note: I haven't written the popping part in main yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the `if` `catch` condition there is no `return`

```
catch(StackEmptyException e)
{
    System.out.print("\n"+e);
    //Should be a return here
}
```

or don't catch it, just throw it

```
int pop() throws StackEmptyException
```

Comment: No there doesn't. The throw replaces a return. Never mind - you edited :)

Comment: My trigger finger is faster than my brain, I meant the `catch`, I've edited

Comment: But If I use throws, it doesn't display the message written in the toString method.

Comment: No but you can handle it in the code that calls this method. It's probably not the preferred option here but it is an option.

Answer (score 0):

You need a return inside of the `catch` block.